# Threaded Binary Tree using semaphores for concurrency

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, binary-tree

I'm pretty unfamiliar with multithreading and synchronization and I have to add semaphore code into given pseudocode that will allow multiple threads to access the threaded binary tree with max concurrency.

The pesudocode gives the node struct that contains:

```
int data
node *leftchild, *rightchild, *prev, *next;
```

and the only function is an `insert(node *root, int data)` which searches to find the parent in the current tree, and then inserts the new node (given it isn't already in the tree) and changing the `prev` and `next` pointers.

I'm not sure how to best to implement the semaphores. My initial idea(s) are:

- Lock/unlock each node as it's being searched. This is to prevent other threads from inserting while I search. Should the parent node be locked as well?

Then for insertion:

- Lock the parent node and the current node to be able to prevent another thread from inserting at the same place at the same time.

Is there a better way to go about this? (assuming it's even correct in the first place)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by locking single nodes in the tree. You acquire a lock on the whole tree, insert the new value, and release the lock. I wouldn't use a semaphore though, but a mutex.

Comment: A bunch of questions come to mind: How big is the tree? How many insertions vs. reads are anticipated? Is it more important for searches to be fast or writes? Are there any high-speed, real-time constraints, or could you batch writes?

Comment: What I'm thinking is that real-world "max concurrency" is typically achieved not with processor threads but with queues and "light" threads. The high performance of NodeJS is an example. But where the data is coming from (and how quickly new data is arriving) is key to knowing whether this would give you an advantage.

Comment: @AndreaLaforgia I have to use semaphores as part of the assignment and am planning on just using a binary semaphore to mirror a mutex lock.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim With the given pseudocode I have and how the question is worded I interpret it as the tree being some arbitrary size containing integers >= 0, non-repeating. The only function is the insert one, so the insertions are what matters - with the search only occurring to preempt the insertion.

Comment: @AndreaLaforgia I also am supposed to "uses semaphores into the pseudocode so that multiple threads can share access to the data structures". So, while locking the entire tree to insert a new value is possible, it isn't ideal. When I was talking about locking single nodes in the tree, I was referring to locking specific nodes to allow multiple threads access into the tree simultaneously - to potentially allow multiple insertions of new nodes.

Comment: The "Threaded" binary tree just threw me for a loop. I hadn't encountered one of those before. Thing is, from what I see on Wikipedia and elsewhere, leftchild/rightchild should be the place where the "threaded" part goes. But there's also a prev/next pair. Is the prev/next pair really just an in-order sorted linked list? If so, then it doesn't seem like it's a "threaded" tree as much as a binary search tree with a linked list bolted on. The question is relevant because it changes what you need to lock and when.

Comment: @Caulay I don't think you can implement any operation on the tree without locking the entire structure.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Yeah, you're right in that the "Threaded binary tree" isn't the best name choice when also talking about multithreading. I also interpreted the tree the same way as the leftchild and rightchild containing the leaves of the tree while the prev/next are pointers to the inorder sorted list. However, the next/prev pointers aren't actively used in the pseudocode given apart from the pointers being altered when a new node is inserted.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you should use a read-write lock. Locking on individual nodes or parts of the tree will become exceptionally difficult if you later decide to switch your tree implementation and is more work then needed.

```
int32_t Tree_insert(Tree *tree, int32_t data) {
    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&tree->rwlock);
    int32_t ret = insert(&tree->root_node, data);
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&tree->rwlock);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is more of a hypothetical scenario where I am supposed to use semaphores to allow multiple threads access to the tree at once. I'm just not sure if what I originally suggested is the right track or not. I know it would be possible (and probably more efficient) to simply lock/unlock the entire tree to insert a node, but it isn't the focus of the exercise unfortunately

Comment: @Caulay what is the exercise's requirement?

Comment: @AndreaLaforgia I have to "use semaphores in the pseudocode so that multiple threads can share access to the data structures. Your goal is to maximize the concurrent use of the
data structures".

Comment: Locks entire tree - does *not* maximize concurrency.